# Jenkins builds when using trunk based development

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I am hearing a lot from people about **trunk based development**. I do not understand how the continuous integration with Jenkins works when doing trunk based development. We use **git** for version control in the organization.

Jenkins jobs are setup to poll git for any changes and if any detected to kick in a build and once the build is success start a deploy.

All developers have access to jenkins and can configure the build to start on a different branch. This code is then deployed in a dev instance for testing. If the developer sees that it is fine they re-configure jenkins build to point back to master. This is manual and it is upto the developer to do this.

There is a pipeline job which runs periodically and overwrites the Jenkins job with a standard job. So even if a developer leaves screws the configuration, still Jenkins manages to keep the build in a sane state.

Now my questions when working **on feature/bugfix branches** with more than one commits, what is the best practice for CI/CD process?

a) Developer will point to their branch **after each of their commit** and deploys to dev instance. This as far as I know is manual and developers can easily forget this.

b) Developer will point Jenkins build to their branch **before raising a Pull request** and deploys to dev instance. If there are multiple commits, the build/deployment could fail because of any of the commits. This is also manual and can be painful for debugging.

c) Developer will run the build locally to make sure tests are passing. Deployment is a dark art and will be left for somebody else to figure out. After the pull request, jenkins will run the build to make sure all tests pass. This is automatic. Now if the build/deployment fails the developer will have figure what went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your c) is the right way to go, but I didn't fully grasp the situation. For trunk-based development, your CI/Jenkins should only be used before merging, not for each commit (i.e., not as a replacement for the local build mechanism). Your developer should build and test their code locally by running the tests manually and debugging if anything goes wrong.

At merge time, you can do pre-merge or post-merge build run. For pre-merge, you configure Jenkins to run for each pull-request branch, and if all tests pass, you merge the pull-request. The upside of this is it is pretty simple to configure. The downside is the build doesn't take into account of new changes in the trunk branch, so trunk might be broken after a merge, even if the tests passed in the pull-request branch.

For post-merge, you can checkout a workspace from your trunk branch, do "git merge" from your pull-request branch, and run the build in the workspace. Only if all tests pass, you commit and push the changes to trunk. The upside is it guarantees the trunk won't be broken. The downside is that you can only run one build at a time, so it will reduce your merging bandwidth.

You can also do both pre-merge and post-merge at the same time. The trunk might still be broken from merging, but you can quickly catch it from post-merge builds and fix it immediately.